# How to load multiple images to WKInterfaceImage

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

WKInterfaceImage's setImageData documentation says "The data can be raw image data or an archived UIImage object. ...... The data object in this parameter may contain multiple images so that the image content can be animated."

Can someone show me a code snippet on how to construct a NSData object from multiple images, that can be loaded into the WKInterfaceImage object?

Here is the best I could interpret how to do this.

```
UIImage * img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"];
UIImage * img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"];

UIImage * img = [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:@[img1, img2] duration:0];

NSData * data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:img];


[self.wkInterfaceImage setImageData:data];
[self.wkInterfaceImage startAnimating];
```

But this does not work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using setImageData use just setImage and pass the image directly.

```
self.wkInterfaceImage setImage:img];
```

Also, you will want to change the duration of your animated image to something greater than 0.

Comment: I do not know how I missed the setImage call, but it works! Thanks!